# How to edit service connection, authorize and run in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

1. I have Azure DevOps pipeline where one of service principals got expired.
2. Now my colleague created new service connection (with service principal) with new name.
3. I went to edit yaml in new branch. I gave new name for azureSubscription.
4. Then "run"
5. Got error "The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use"
6. I press "Authorize resources" and getting successful message.
7. "Run new"
8. Getting back to 5.point and never get pipeline executed correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the correct service connection name. You can also navigate and enable the box **grant access to all pipelines** on the service connection settings.

[image]

If the problem is not resolved, I would follow the below steps:

- remove the service connection
- Add it again
- Logout
- Login and run the pipeline

Comment: "Grant access permission to all pipelines" is already checked

Comment: @Kenny_I did you follow the steps written above? Sometimes there could be an error on the current session. Logout/Login may work for you.